# Tool for Mobile Screen Export/TV out to external monitor

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, blackberry

I understand this is purely a coding related forum, but i believe techies can help me for this issue.

I have a requirement to demonstrate the running mobile applications in TV out(monitor). I have android, iPhone, iPad and Blackberry applications to be demoed. Can anyone you please help in identifying a tool free or paid, which will serve my purpose.

Using emulator we can do this, but it doesn’t not give exhibits if any device specific services.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need HDMI adapter for iPhone/iPad.
For Android some model provide VGA output via phone jack. Check with what you have first. Samsung Galaxy S2 has dedicate adapter for video output in the same fashion as iOS devices.
Newer model of Android devices also support HDMI output by itself.

I can't be specific here but good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found "Apple Digital AV Adapter" which helps for TV out any contents that running in iPhone or iPad.

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD098ZM/A?fnode=MTc0MjU4NjE&mco=MTcyMTgxODY